# lstlining changing font in moredelim

Tags: listings

`lstlisting` is not using the `identifierstyle` font inside of the `moredelim` that makes the identifier name red. In the example, the first `varname` is in tt font but the second is in roman. I want the second `varname` to also be in tt font but red. What am I doing wrong?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}

\lstset{
language=C++,
identifierstyle={\texttt},
moredelim=**[is][\color{red}]{@}{@},
}% lstset

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
varname
@varname@
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: use `moredelim=**[is][\color{red}\tt]{@}{@}`

Comment: @Marijn No, not `\tt`! Use `\ttfamily`.

Answer (score 1):

Add `\ttfamily`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}

\lstset{
language=C++,
identifierstyle={\texttt},
moredelim=**[is][\color{red}\ttfamily]{@}{@},
}% lstset

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
varname
@varname@
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]